# Separating 2 div equally

Tags: html, css, css-position

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkVvG.png)

I want to get rid of the padding-left of DIV 1 and padding-right of DIV 2 in order to separate the 2 divs in the middle equall. I want to . Please take note that I am not using Bootstrap. (Please See Image 1)

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-50">
            <div class="card-box">
                <h4 class="header-title">View Data</h4>
                <div class="col-100">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-50">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <a class="btn-excel" href="#"><span>Excel</span></a>
                                <a class="btn-pdf" href="#"><span>PDF</span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-50">
                            <form class="pull-right">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">
                            <span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-100">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-50">
            <div class="card-box">
                <h4 class="header-title">View Data</h4>
                <div class="table-container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-50">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <a class="btn-excel" href="#"><span>Excel</span></a>
                                <a class="btn-pdf" href="#"><span>PDF</span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-50">
                            <form class="pull-right">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">
                            <span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-100">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is my CSS Code:

```
*, *::before, *::after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

```
.row::after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
```

}

```
.row {
margin-left: -0.75rem !important;
margin-right: -0.75rem !important;
```

}

```
.col-50 {
width: 50%;
float: left;
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-left: 0.75rem;
padding-right: 0.75rem;
```

}

```
.card-box {
padding: 5px 20px 20px 20px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
background-clip: padding-box;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
background-color: #ffffff;
box-shadow: 0 0px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 1px 0px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
display: block;
min-height: 0.01%;
overflow-x: auto;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `first-of-type` and `last-of-type` selectors to select the first and last columns and then, **remove the left padding of the first column and right padding of the last column** like this:

```
.col-50:first-of-type {
  padding-left: 0rem;
}

.col-50:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0rem;
}
```

The class `.col-50` already has `padding-left: 0.75rem;` and `padding-right: 0.75rem;` which will add equal spacing between the columns, so no need to edit this.

```
.col-50 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
}
```

Here's the working codepen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evxyNb

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto glad i could help :)